# how to set a price rule for two specific individual products in magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I have to create a shopping cart price rule for two specific products so that when I add these two products I got the discount on the total price.

I tried many conditions in the condition tab but it didn't happening. this is my condition tab

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

If total quantity  is  2  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
    SKU  is  zol_b_lrg, sport_b_lrg
    Frequently is 100
```

Now what is wrong with these condition.
I select the `Fixed amount discount for whole cart` from the `Apply` tab and set the value in the next tab eg 10

But nothing is happening. Help me with this please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that 'status' is set to 'active'?